# How to remove all html tags from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to remove all the html tags from a particular string its showing error.

Here is my string:

```
<p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>
```

My jQuery code is here:

```
var item = <p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>;
item = item.replace(/~/g, '');
item = item.replace(/<p>/g, '');
item = item.replace('</p>'/g, '');
var splitArray = item.split('<br />');
var l = splitArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    out = out + "<li><span class='sp_icon sp_star_icon'></span> "
          + splitArray[i].trim() + "</li>";
}
console.log(item);
```

Comment: Does the error refer to the fact that your first string is not wrapped in quotes? Or is that not how it actually looks in your code? Please make sure you're posting exactly what you're using. And tell us the error, as well.

Comment: your variable `item` must be in quotes.

Comment: Also the third replace (`'</p>'/g`) is strange. I don't think that will work at all

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can strip out all the html-tags with a regular expression: /<(.|\n)*?>/g

Described in detail here: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm

In your JS-Code it would look like this:

```
item = item.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
```

Comment: OP should note: this isn't recommended as your regex will never be able to be as lenient and all-encompassing as real browser HTML parsing engines. If you're removing **known** HTML, then it's cool, but if this HTML is unknown then you should really seek a proper HTML parsing engine, most conveniently, the native browser DOM :)

Answer (score 9):

Don't do it yourself, let the DOM do it for you.

E.g. (with jQuery)

```
jQuery("<p>Hi there</p>...").text();
    // => "Hi there..."
```

E.g. (without jQuery)

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = "<p>Hi there</p>...";
(d.textContent || d.innerText); // => "Hi there..."
```

Answer (score 6):

With vanilla JS you can do it like this

```js
var item = '<p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>';

function getText(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
}

console.log(getText(item));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var item = '<p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>'

item = item.replace(/<\/?.+?>/ig, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope your are only trying to remove HTML markup from the string. Following should work. Though might need to test.

```
filtered = yourString.replace(/<[a-z]{1}>.*?<\/[a-z]{1}>/gi, "");
```

In case you just wanted to get rid of  and  markup and keep the text inside it then

```
filtered = yourString.replace(/<\/{0,1}[a-z]+>/gi, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's text method.

```
var item = '<p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>';
console.log($(item).text());
```

You can check fiddle code at http://jsfiddle.net/gL7fufax/

Answer (score 0):

As asked for your particular string (to remove `<p>` elements):

```
item = item.replace(/<\/?p>/g,''); // will globally find “<p>” and “</p>” only
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your string in a jQuery object:

```
var removeElements = function(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector).remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}

var removedPString = removeElements("<p>Hi there</p> ~ wifi free <p>this is test</p> ~ breakfast free <p>This is another test</p>", "p");
```

Comment: This won't work as it will remove not only the tags, but also the text inside the tags

Comment: I have use this it's worked.